# How to merge string elements into one output seperated with `,`

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab data from div elements and output them seperated with `,` in this way `a, b`
How can I achieve this?
For my example, text in `p` output should look like `test, test222 dada`

```js
let desc = document.querySelectorAll(".desc");
let output = document.querySelectorAll(".output");
let items = [];

desc.forEach((item, i) => {
console.log(item.dataset.sentence);
output.textContent += item[i];
})
```

```html
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test">

</div>

<div class="desc" data-sentence="test222 dada">

</div>

<p class="output">

</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution demonstrating the use of advanced ECMAScript syntax features like double **destructuring** in the function signature, array spread (`[...iterable]`) along with `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
let desc = document.querySelectorAll(".desc");
let output = document.querySelector(".output");
output.textContent = [...desc].map(({dataset: { sentence } }) => sentence).join(', ');
```

```html
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test"></div>
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test222 dada"></div>
<p class="output"></p>
```

Explanations:

1. `[...desc]` *spreads* the `NodeList` you have in `desc` into an **array**, which allows for the use of Array methods like `map` and `join`.
2. `({dataset: { sentence } })` destructures the object being passed to the map iterator. The signature basically says "I expect to be passed an object that has a `dataset` property, which is an object that has a `sentence` property. Give me that `sentence` as a local variable inside the function body."

Comment: pros: clean codes, cons: loop one time more of the array.

Comment: @ikhvjs Sure you could save one iteration using `reduce`. I wouldn't usually consider optimizing tasks like this one, though.

Comment: The time you use `spreads`, you already use one loop. It would be the same as `reduce`.

Comment: I was talking `map` and `join`.

Comment: I see. I am talking about `spread`.

Comment: Still I'd prefer spreading over `Array.prototype.map.call(desc, ...)` unless I really need the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you could try:

1. Store your text to an array

The way you get the text with `item.dataset.sentence` is totally fine, you just need to put them in an array to use later.

```
let text = [];
desc.forEach((item, i) => {
    text.push(item.dataset.sentence);
})
```

2. Convert the array to string using `join()`

`text.join(',')` => `'test,test222 dada'`

3. Update the content

`document.querySelectorAll(".output")` will not work as it will return an array, you will need to change it to `document.querySelector(".output")` to have an element.

```js
const desc = document.querySelectorAll(".desc");
const output = document.querySelector(".output");
const text = [];

desc.forEach(item => text.push(item.dataset.sentence));
output.textContent = text.join(',');
```

```html
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test"></div>
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test222 dada"></div>
<p class="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost finish it but you make some mistake.

When you select output, you only need to use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`.

```js
let desc = document.querySelectorAll(".desc");
let output = document.querySelector(".output");
const data = [];

desc.forEach((item) => {
    data.push(item.dataset.sentence);
});

output.textContent = data.join(",");
```

```html
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test">

</div>

<div class="desc" data-sentence="test222 dada">

</div>

<p class="output">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `join()` function by making an array out of. the strings you want to join and using the separator argument like this

```
const output = ['a','b'].join(','); //output = "a,b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You fetched all elements with `output` class. So, you should concatenate text to the first matching element. Instead of `output.textContent`, you should add `output[0].textContent`. Also, if the element is not the last element, add `,`  to the result.

```js
let desc = document.querySelectorAll(".desc");
let output = document.querySelectorAll(".output");
let items = [];

desc.forEach((item, i, arr) => {
  output[0].textContent += item.dataset.sentence;
  if (i < arr.length - 1) output[0].textContent += ', '
})
```

```html
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test">

</div>

<div class="desc" data-sentence="test222 dada">

</div>

<p class="output">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let desc = document.querySelectorAll(".desc");
let output = document.getElementById("output");
let items = [];

desc.forEach((item, i) => {
  items[i] = item.dataset.sentence
})

output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items.join()));
```

```html
<p id='output'> Output </p>


<div class="desc" data-sentence="a-teste">

</div>

<div class="desc" data-sentence="b-testes c-testes">

</div>
```

try this, but read this guide.

https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/

**What not to do with data attributes**
Store content that should be accessible. If the content should be seen or read on a page, don’t only put them in data attributes, but make sure that content is in the HTML content somewhere.

Read about function querySelectorAll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

becausa on **output** (let) you recive a  NodeList

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
      let desc = document.querySelectorAll(".desc")
      let output = document.querySelector(".output")
      let item = []
      desc.forEach((elem)=>{
          item.push(elem.dataset.sentence)//push each data sentence into array
      })
     var Mystring = ""  //start with empty string
      k = 0
     while(k<item.length-1){
       //concatenate empty string with first element and then the result with  
       //"," and the next till the last but one element
       Mystring = Mystring.concat(item[k]).concat(", ")
       k = k + 1
     }
    //concatenate result to last element
     data = Mystring.concat(item[item.length-1])
  
     output.textContent = data
```

```html
<div class="desc" data-sentence="test">

</div>

<div class="desc" data-sentence="test222 dada">

</div>

<p class="output">

</p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This snipet is for the general case where you might have even k elements with the same class and wish to concatenate their data.